# Android GridView Item Selectors change position and duplicate

Tags: android, gridview, selector, adapter

I have a GridView layout with 3 columns and several rows that contains pictures taken from Facebook. When I select an image, a selector appears for that item in the gridView as normal. (I don't use the android selector but a custom layout linked below.)

The problem is this: if I select one or more items, when I scroll down the screen to see more pictures I discover that other items have already been selected! Moreover, if I scroll up to see the items I've previously selected, the selectors change their position. It seems to me that the index of each selector update every time I scroll the screen.

I created a personal ImageAdapter to inflate the pictures from facebook. **Here the getView:**

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v;
        ImageView imageView = null;
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.photos_item, null);
        }else{
            v = convertView;
        }     
        imageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.image);
        v.setTag(imageView);
        if (arrayPhotos.get(position).getPictureSource() != null){
            Log.i(TAG, "Position in GridView = " + Integer.valueOf(position).toString());
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(arrayPhotos.get(position).getPictureSource(), imageView);
        }
        return v;

    }
```

**Here the onItemClick:**

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

View checkedItem;

    checkedItem = (View) view.findViewById(R.id.check);

    fbPicture = arrayFbPictures.get(position);
    Log.i(TAG, "Position = " + arrayFbPictures.indexOf(fbPicture));
    Log.i(TAG, "PicId = " + fbPicture.getPictureID());

    if( fbPicture.isChoosed() ){

        Log.i(TAG, "checkIcon DISACTIVATED");
        fbPicture.setChoosed(false);
        checkedItem.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        parent.invalidate();
    }
    else{

        Log.i(TAG, "checkIcon ACTIVATED");
        fbPicture.setChoosed(true);
        checkedItem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        parent.invalidate();
    }
}
```

**That is the xml of the GridView:**

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit" 
    android:columnWidth="96dp"
    android:stretchMode="spacingWidth"
    android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp" >
</GridView>
```

**And this the xml of the custom selector:**

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/check"
   android:layout_width="96dp"
   android:layout_height="96dp"
   android:background="@color/black_trasparency_light"
   android:visibility="invisible" > 

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_check"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_check_colored_48" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because GridView uses view recycling. When you scroll down the GridView, instead of creating new views to put in the bottom, GridView reuses the ones that disappear from the top. What this means is that you have to remember to fully set the state of the view inside the call to getView().

That's a little hard to digest, so here's some code:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  ...

  View checkedItem = (View) v.findViewById(R.id.check);

  fbPicture = arrayFbPictures.get(position);
  if (fbPicture.isChoosed()) {
     checkedItem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  } else {
     checkedItem.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
  }

  return v;
}
```

The code above is setting the checked state of the convertView every time getView() is called, so the recycled view will not retain any of its previous state.

PS. The is done to conserve the memory and to improve performance of GridView and ListView. You can watch this awesome [presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) for more information.